# Keyboard shortcuts - function keys - created in Qt app don't work on OSX

Tags: macos, qt, menu, shortcut

I have a program that in main menu uses certain shortcuts. It works in windows and Linux. When porting to mac, certain shortcuts will not work.

The menu is created using QT Designer. It looks like this

```
QAction *actDelete;
actDelete = new QAction(MainWindow);
actDelete->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actDelete"));
menu_Edit->addAction(actDelete);
actDelete->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Delete", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
actDelete->setShortcut(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Del", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));


QAction *act1;
act1 = new QAction(MainWindow);
act1->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("act1"));
menu1->addAction(act1);
act1->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Action 1", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
act1->setShortcut(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "F12", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
```

The only keys that don't work are the function keys, and Delete (for Delete the reason may be that Mac has replaced it with a key that technically is backspace... but it is still called Delete so it should work ?)

Other key combinations work... The function keys are assigned to other functionality it seems...

It seems that it is impossible to remove the default functionality of function keys through code (is that really true ?) - so I went and clicked the button to 'Enable "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys."'. At this point I can press the function keys and see what code they generate (like `key=0x100003B` for  `ctrl + F12` or `cmd + F12`).

In the main window constructor, after instantiating ui, I tried

```
#if defined Q_OS_MACX
m_ui->act1->setShortcut(tr("CTRL+F12")); // still nothing happening
m_ui->act1->setShortcut(Qt::CTRL+Qt::Key_F12);  // same, no effect on mac (though if i put it for windows the ctrl+F12 does have the desired effect
#endif
```

Qt version 4.7-4.8, OSX 10.6.8 building using g++

Comment: F11 and F12 are used by the OS by default (although they can be unbound by the user). No idea about delete, though.

Comment: Just updated - upon testing on mac I can see the default mac actions happening. But there has to be a way to redefine these actions by the developer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a definition of shortcuts for Mac

```
#if defined (Q_OS_MACX)
    m_ui->act1->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_F12));
#endif
```

Added Backspace instead of Delete for Mac.