# Qt Menu Shortcuts not working on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cocoa, qt5

I have a Qt 5 application that was developed on Debian Linux and now I'm porting it and enhancing it for OS X. When I brought it over, all of the menu shortcuts were present in the forms editor. The visual shortcut had been changed to reflect use of the command key rather than the control key. So, the ui file for the Login action looks like this:

```
<action name="LoginAction">
 <property name="text">
  <string>Log in...</string>
 </property>
 <property name="shortcut">
  <string>Ctrl+L</string>
 </property>
</action>
```

However, the only keyboard shortcuts that work now are the default ones that OS X uses, e.g. command-Q.

I have seen discussion on the Qt forums indicating that it is related to Qt 5 handing off shortcuts to Cocoa. This post [Keyboard shortcuts - function keys - created in Qt app don't work on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852370/keyboard-shortcuts-function-keys-created-in-qt-app-dont-work-on-osx) suggested a workaround which I incorporated,

```
#if defined (Q_OS_MACX)
    ui->LoginAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_L));
    ui->LoginAction->setShortcutContext(Qt::ApplicationShortcut);
#endif
```

but the shortcuts still don't work. Command-L does not trigger LoginAction.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with using a menu that is not native to OS X. The shortcuts from the non-native menu actions don't seem to trigger anything. In the UI designer view, you need to to check the native menu box in the top level menu properties, and you need to make the shortcuts application level shortcuts. There is a checkbox on the QAction properties for this.

You can also do it programmatically like so:

```
QAction *myAction = new QAction("My action");
myAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence("CTRL+M"));
myAction->setShortcutContext(Qt::ApplicationShortcut);

QMenu *myMenu = new QMenu("My Menu");
myMenu->addAction(myAction);
ui->menuBar->addMenu(myMenu);

ui->menuBar->setNativeMenuBar(true);
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted. (Yes, you can do this for your own answers.) This makes it clear to others that your question has been dealt with :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and found out that it was happening because I was not using the [native menu bar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#nativeMenuBar-prop). In my **MainWindow** constructor I was defining this:

```
ui->menuBar->setNativeMenuBar(false);
```

And some action shortcuts (e.g. `Command+S` and `Command+O`) were not working on **OSX**. So, I just removed that line and the shortcuts are working fine now.

I could not find the reason of this issue, but it seems to be related to **OSX** shortcuts.

Anyway, I hope this answer may be helpful for you or other people that are facing the same issue.

Comment: Not the answer, but it led me to the answer. Thank you.